# Android App Stopped when moving to another activity after amount of time

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am working on a Bluetooth control App using Android , when the user click the Pair button to start the connection with another Bluetooth device , i want to open another activity after amount of time ( when the pairing between the two devices is finished) .

The problem is that the App is stopped after pairing between devices . what is the problem in my code ? i have searched a lot but i havent found any solution .Please any help would be appreciated .

thanks in advance

**this is my code**

```
public class DevicesListActivity extends Activity 
{
     private ListView mListView;
     private DeviceListAdapter mAdapter;
     //the List that we will receive from the Main Activity
     private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> PassedDeviceList;

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices_list);

      PassedDeviceList      =        getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("device.list");

    mListView       = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DevicesList_lv);

    mAdapter        = new DeviceListAdapter(this);
    mAdapter.setData(PassedDeviceList);


    mAdapter.setListener(new DeviceListAdapter.OnPairButtonClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onPairButtonClick(int position)
        {

            showToast("PairedBTN Clicked");
            BluetoothDevice device = PassedDeviceList.get(position);

            if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
            {
                unpairDevice(device);
            }

            else 
            {
                showToast("Pairing...");
                pairDevice(device);
            }
        }
    });

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)); 



}

 //***** We will Pair with the Selected Device then Go to the Control Screen
   private void pairDevice(final BluetoothDevice device)
   {
      try 
      {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

        showToast("YOu have Paired with Device Name:" + device.getName()+" And Address: " + device.getAddress() );

        //***** Make an intent to start next activity.*****
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

               Intent i = new Intent(DevicesListActivity.this, MobileControl.class);
               //Change the activity.
               String address = device.getAddress();
               i.putExtra("ADDRESS", address); //this will be received at Control Activity
               startActivity(i);
               //finish();

           }

        }, 10000);



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output.

Comment: @Nanoc  I am testing the App on a real device because the emulator didn't support Bluetooth

Comment: That has no meaning here , still missing your logcat output.

Comment: @ sourabh bans,@Nanoc we can't solve the Problem without the Logcat ?

Comment: Solve a crash without a logcat? you will get no help.

Comment: @Nanoc the logcat is empty since there is no Bluetooth in the emulator . The App work Successfully until the pairing is done , then  when the app try to move to the next activity its stopped

Comment: when I have removed the code that responsible for  moving to the next activity  the problem  is gone

Comment: When you move to the next activity it crash and you get the trace on the logcat, please post it.

Comment: You can still get logcat output in real device if you have adb.